# Can I interpret Avogadro's principle of gases from the state equation (ideal gas law)?

Tags: ideal-gas, thermodynamics

Considering the molar form of the ideal gas law I can solve for the ratio of some gas volume, $V$ divided by the number of gas particles, $n$ in mols
$$\frac{V}{n}=\frac{RT}{P}$$

And $R$ is the Universal Gas Constant

So then if I roughly have 1 mol of gas occupying 22.4 liters of space (the gas 'volume') then I can expect that the temperature, $T$ and pressure, $P$ on the right side of the equation are at the standard  values.

Is this interpretation right?

Comment: $T$ and $p$ can both vary here as long as their ratio is constant.

Comment: @march good point. I suppose then that underlines a fact that 'standard ' temperature and pressure are somewhat an arbitrary choice. But the ratio must be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Title is not matching the description. Answer as per title
will be : Yes one can do this but it is usually done the other way. In most of the books first the
equation PV=mRT (R is gas constant whose value depend on nature of gas) is established then they use avogadros principle to state it in molar form as
       PV=(nM)RT
            ; V/n=MRT/P
                 ; V/n=R'T/P
 Using avogadros law one can observe that R' is a constant, independent of nature of gas.
Thus R'=(MR) is called universal gas constant.